# How to traverse to the end of a complete tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, priority-queue

Complete binary tree: A complete binary tree is a binary tree in which every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes are as far left as possible.

How to: traverse in order recursively a tree like this?

```
    1
  2   3
4  5
```

Where 2 and 3 is a node of 1 and 4 and 5 is a node of 2.

Comment: Google "fundamental algorithms": http://www.cse.tum.de/vtc/FundAlg, http://www.algosort.com and many others (7 670 000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tree-traversal there are basically 3 algorithms

`Preorder`, `Inorder` and `Postorder`

```
void inorder(root_node)
{
    if(root_node != null)
    {
        inorder(root_node->left);
        println(root_node->value);
        inorder(root_node->right);
    }
}
```

Output: 4 2 5 1 3

You can refer this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) for more details.

EDIT:

To answer your question (in comments section), If you want to traverse all the nodes acc. to their level in tree, you should use graph traversal algorithms. in your case it'll be BFS - Breadth First Search.

(Note: tree is also a kind of graph)

See [here](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cis680/cis680Ch14.html#QQ1-46-92) for details.

Comment: so is it impossible to traverse the tree in the order of 1 2 3 4 5?

Comment: you are looking for `Breadth-First Search`: see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal

Answer (score 0):

This question is kindof vague and it depends what you are after, whats most effective etc.

Have a look at:
[Tree traversal algorithms for a binary tree](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Programming_Concepts/Tree_traversal_algorithms_for_a_binary_tree)